# Verifying that "being isomorphic" is an equivalence relation on the objects of a category

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

On page 7 of *Topology: A Categorical Approach* by Bradley, Bryson and Terilla I am asked to verify what I've written in the title of this post.

**My attempt:**

*Reflexivity:*

The isomorphism from $X$ to $X$ is $\text{id}_X$, since $\text{id}_X$ is its own inverse. Therefore $X \cong X$.

*Symmetry:*

If $X \cong Y$ that means there is an invertible morphism $f \colon X \to Y$. Say its inverse is $g \colon Y \to X$. When we show that $g$ is the left and right inverse of $f$, we are showing that $f$ is the right and left inverse of $g$ (respectively), so that $f$ is the inverse morphism of $g$ and therefore $Y \cong X$.

*Transitivity:*

Suppose we have objects $X, Y$ and $Z$ such that $X \cong Y$ and $Y \cong Z$. There are thus invertible morphisms $f \colon X \to Y$ and $g \colon Y \to Z$. By the composition axiom of categories, we know that $gf \colon X \to Z$ is a morphism. We want to show that $gf$ is invertible, hence $X \cong Z$.

We can compose the inverse morphisms $f^{-1} \colon Y \to X$ and $g^{-1} \colon Z \to Y$ to get $f^{-1}g^{-1} \colon Z \to X$. Composing $f^{-1}g^{-1}$ with $gf$, we get

\begin{align*}
(f^{-1}g^{-1})(gf) &= f^{-1}(g^{-1}g)f\\
&= f^{-1}\text{id}_Y f\\
&= f^{-1}f\\
&= \text{id}_X,
\end{align*}

and similarly on the right side, hence $X \cong Z$ as desired.

**Question:**

Do I need to prove some kind of generalized associativity to justify the manipulations I used to prove transitivity? The category axiom for associativity only says that $f(gh) = (fg)h$ for suitably defined morphisms.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Associativity holds as much as you want by induction just as in the case of monoids. The proof is fine, and conceptually you can think of equivalence relations themselves as special categories, with each of the axioms being a special case of a categorical axiom or structure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your help. I am looking at Lang's *Algebra* right now and one of the first things he does is discuss associativity for monoids like you're talking about. I will dwell on what you've written. Thanks again.